# Accessing a class function from another class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a simple program in Python using Tkinter but I'm having trouble accessing functions/attributes from classes different than the one I currently am.

I start off by instantiating the main class which is called "MainProgram"

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk, filedialog
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class MainProgram:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("850x500")
        self.CenterWindow(self.master)
        self.master.title("Projeto AED")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        # Hide the main window while the user is unauthenticated
        self.master.withdraw()
        # Open the login window
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Login(self.newWindow)

    def CenterWindow(self, target):
        target.update_idletasks()
        if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance(): app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        else: app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        screen_width = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().width()
        screen_height = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().height()
        size = tuple(int(_) for _ in target.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        x = screen_width / 2 - size[0] / 2
        y = screen_height / 2 - size[1] / 2
        target.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = MainProgram(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The MainProgram class has a function inside of it called "CenterWindow" that uses QtGui to center Tkinter's window. This function needs to be accessed by pretty much every other class I have (Login and Register - see code below)

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x250")


        # I cannot access this app
        app.CenterWindow(self.master)


        self.master.title("Iniciar Sessão")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.focus_force()
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = "Open register", command = self.OpenRegister)
        self.button1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

    def OpenRegister(self):
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Register(self.newWindow)

class Register:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x375")


        # I can access app here
        app.CenterWindow(self.master)


        self.master.title("Efetuar Registo")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.focus_force()
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = "Back to login", command = self.BackToLogin)
        self.button1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

    def BackToLogin(self):
        # I can access app with no problem here
        self.master.destroy()
        app.newWindow.update()
        app.newWindow.deiconify()
```

After instantiating the class MainProgram, it's init function is going to create a new window with toplevel that then is linked to my Login class. After the window spawns there's a a button that opens another new window exactly the same way as the MainProgram did Login, but instead is an instance of Register. In this window (Register) I can access my app variable (instance of my MainProgram class) and then have access to the CenterWindow function. But in my Login class I cannot do that. Any ideas?

Comment: If `self.master` is the toplevel created inside class method of `MainProgram`, I think `self.master.master` will be the instance of `MainProgram`.  So use `self.master.master.CenterWindow(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 self.master.master is a Toplevel object, its not the instance of MainProgram class

Comment: Both of us are wrong, `self.master.master` is the root window.  I think you need to pass the instance of `MainProgram` (`self`) when creating `Login` class.

Answer (score 0):

This has no business being a class method. Just make it a normal function. You don't need PySide either.

```
def center(target):
    target.update_idletasks()
    x = target.winfo_vrootwidth() / 2 - target.winfo_width() / 2
    y = target.winfo_vrootheight() / 2 - target.winfo_height() / 2
    target.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
```

Which you can use or import like any other function.

```
center(self.master)
```

If you really *really* want to use classes you should make it a parent class or a mixin.

Comment: I used Qtgui because if you have multiple monitors winfo_vrootwidth() and .winfo_vrootheight() will give the monitors width and height combined and not the width and height of the main monitor.
I also understand I could make it a normal function but is there any reason why I can call the method from the Register class and not the Login one?

Comment: @Darwin1337 the reason is that `app` is not a name that has been created yet. You are in the process of creating is when you tried to use it. And it's not that you "could" make it a function, you SHOULD make it a function. There's no benefits to this being in that class, only downsides.